# Manager not found error in sharepoint using MS Flows.Can anyone help me to fix the issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have created flows connected to the SharePoint list but I am getting

> manager not found error.

[image: manager not found error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a step "Get User Porfile" before "Get manager":

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it is not working.

Comment: Did you configure the property manager for this user?

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine now.Before i didn't update the manager in Azure Active directory.